# How do I exclude particular words from a match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
  id, text
FROM
  comments
WHERE
  lower(text) LIKE '%hell%'
ORDER BY len(text) ASC
```

This matches any text that contains `hell`. However, I want to exclude a particular word from a match: "seashells". How can I write an SQL query that matches everything that contains `hell`, but ignores `seashells`?

Examples:

- He said **hell**o to the boy — matches.
- Are there seashells on the beach? — no match.
- Uns**hell**ed seashells — matches.

Comment: FYI unless you are using a case sensitive collation, you don't even need `lower` - in fact you wouldn't want to use it because it will reduce performance.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Are these literally the things you are looking for or have you generalised?  Also, what would "hello seashells" do?

Comment: @LoztInSpace "**hell**o seashells" matches.

Comment: Aside: [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: @HABO That is not a problem in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try keeping your current logic but checking for`%hell%` after first removing `seashells` from the text:

```
SELECT id, text
FROM comments
WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(text, 'seashell', '')) LIKE '%hell%'
ORDER BY LEN(text);
```

Note that regex search would be a much better way to handle your requirement, but SQL Server does not have much built in regex support.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `REPLACE(LOWER(text), 'seashell', '')` instead?

Comment: Any idea how this could be improved to match multiple words? `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(text), 'seashell', ''), 'eggshell', ''), 'subshell', '')` is rather verbose.

Comment: @Flux If you need to cover multiple words then you really need something like regex support, which as mentioned SQL Server does not have.  In any case, I have answered the question you actually did ask.

Comment: @Flux . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.  And although I upvoted this, I think the replacement value should be almost anything other than `''`.  You don't want `'heseashellsll'` to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try
`Not Like` in Sql Query. Here is something you can try.

```
SELECT
id, text
FROM
comments
WHERE
lower(text) LIKE '%hell%'
ORDER BY len(text) ASC

EXCEPT

SELECT
id, text
FROM
comments
WHERE
lower(text) LIKE '%seashells%'
OR
lower(text) LIKE '%other_word%'
ORDER BY len(text) ASC
```

To exclude some specific key word containing **hell** .
Note: NOT / LIKE  IS CASE SENSITIVE.

Comment: this will ignore all the words having "hell" and not just seashell